# What are these cracks in the side of my bicycle tyre called? Does this mean that my tyre is gone?

Tags: tire

I found out cracks in my bicycle tyre. I am not sure if the tyre is damaged. Following is a picture for reference
I would like to know what can be the possible causes for these cracks and how to avoid them.
[image: The cracks]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to ride on cracked tyre?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31783/is-it-safe-to-ride-on-cracked-tyre)

Comment: The crack in the sidewall is likely due to riding underinflated, or leaving the bike sitting for months with a flat tire.  It makes the tire more apt to burst, but not severely so -- plan on replacing it eventually, but it should be good for a few weeks, or the summer, depending on how much you ride and how you treat it.

Comment: Those cracks are called 'cracks'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not ideal, the tyre is approaching end of life, but the tube is unlikely to burst through that crack because the structural part of the tyre (the threads) still there and are still somewhat protected from the weather.

Do plan on replacing it, but you should get at least months or more of riding.  Basically wear the tread out some more then replace both tyres.

Comment: If the tyre is overaged the threading is likely to burst as well. I would not ride and replace it ASAP.

Comment: @Carel I've witnessed a tyre like that exploding just when standing in the garden.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say, it's time to replace the tire. It doesn't really matter what caused it - could have been low quality, age, or extended use. The cracks mean the layers the tire is made of are separating and in the long run you will see more punctures because the material is softening. A brand-name tire costs 15 to 25 EUR/USD/GBP which I consider low enough to not take the risk of punctures.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, that is called "Dry Rot", and it's caused by rubber drying out and getting less pliable.  Commonly happens when a bike is on a concrete floor not being used(like in a garage or storage shed) for a long period of time.  It will make your tire brittle, and sometimes will make it unsafe.  A little dry rot usually isn't detrimental, a lot can split the sidewall of the tire causing a blowout.  Yes, you should change the tire.

Comment: in which region is it called dry rot? In the uk that term refers to certain fungal infections of structural timber and we say the tyre has perished.

Comment: @JoeK I googled dry rot, and it does appear to be a general use term that's applied to both automotive and bicycle tires. Sidewall weathering is probably a more accurate term, and I agree that dry rot overlaps with the fungal infection issue and isn't technically accurate in rubber tires. That said, it does seem that people are using the term. We can shake our fists at them, but they will respond that we are pedants, so...

Comment: @WeiwenNg gwgl confirms it's a US term. It doesn't really matter very much. I'd rather have "dry rot" tyres than timbers, hey.