# 5~10mm rupture (crack) on my tire - should I replace it?

Tags: tire

[image: Tire tear]
This is on my rear tire. I ride about 100 miles a week and the tire has been fine. Will this lead to a blow out?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46858/what-are-these-cracks-in-the-side-of-my-bicycle-tyre-called-does-this-mean-that

Comment: You should consider what may have caused it.  The diagonal marks along the sidewall suggest that underinflation may be the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The tyre wall appears to be splitting or the layers are coming away from each other. Yes, that's bad because it will lead to failure of the tyre. Failure probably isn't imminent but you should replace it as soon as is practical; new tyres aren't very expensive.

Comment: Agreed - its in the direction of the threads so there's a good 10mm of unsupported tube  Eventually your tube will bulge out and puncture, or your rim brake will catch it.   Its not a "stop riding immediately" but you should replace the rear tyre as soon as you can afford to.

Comment: There is a second layer of threads going to opposite direction that is intact. If it was also broken, there would be a visible bulge.

Comment: I agree. In a pinch one can put a piece of old tire (or tube or cardboard if you don’t have anything else) under the cut to support it and a bit of glue on the outside to prevent further fraying but that’s a temporary solution (though I’ve done it even for road tires with 8bar pressure). At least a failure on the back wheel is relatively save.